# 'Newtonsoft.Json.Linq.JArray' is not compatible with expected type 'Newtonsoft.Json.Linq.JObject C# .Net Core 7.0

Tags: c#, .net-core, json.net, json-deserialization

Very confused... I just copied this from another .NET Core program that's working and verified that `jsonString` is valid json.

```
using Newtonsoft.Json;
using Newtonsoft.Json.Linq;

public static JObject StringToObject(string jsonString)
{
    // error occurs here
    JObject o = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<JObject>(jsonString); 
    return o;
}
```

When I deserialize the string, I get this error:

> Deserialized JSON type 'Newtonsoft.Json.Linq.JArray' is not compatible with expected type 'Newtonsoft.Json.Linq.JObject

Where is the `JArray` coming from?.. everything is a `JObject`.

EDIT:
Thanks to Jon Skeet. The `jsonString` is returned from a method that reads a database and creates a json string array.

Here's the string:

```
[
    { "code_seq": 1, "code_type": "ARM", "code_data": "Debt Collection" },
    { "code_seq": 2, "code_type": "FFC", "code_data": "Focus Four Construction" },
    { "code_seq": 3, "code_type": "UDD", "code_data":"UnDistracted Driving" },
    { "code_seq": 4, "code_type": "LMS", "code_data": "LMS + Habit Builder" }
]
```

EDIT 2:
Someone closed the question and added:

```
Closed. This question needs debugging details. It is not currently accepting answers.
Edit the question to include desired behavior, a specific problem or error, and the shortest code necessary to reproduce the problem. This will help others answer the question.
```

I thought it was pretty obvious but here goes...

The "desired behavior" was to convert the json string to an object.  However, the json string was an array and I was trying to turn it into a JObject... singular object, when in fact it was an array and needed to be turned into a JArray.  The "specific problem" was identified in the title of the post and the "shortest code necessary to reproduce the problem" was listed in the original post.  The shortest code for the fix is:

```
JArray o = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<JArray>(jsonString);
```

Hopefully, that satisfies whoever closed the post.  Many thanks to Alexander Petrov and Jon Skeet for pointing to the issue.

Comment: Show `jsonString` content. `{...}` - object, `[...]` - array.

Comment: "verified that jsonString is valid json" - yes, it may well be valid JSON, but is it valid JSON for an object? (As Alexander says, show the JSON. In general, always show a [mcve] if you possibly can. In this case it should be really easy to do so.)

Comment: You are correct.  The string comes from a method that reads a database and returns an array.  Put your comment in an answer and I'll accept it.

Comment: Use `JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<JToken>(jsonString);` instead.  `JToken` is the base class for `JArray`, `JObject` and `JValue` and can represent any well-formed JSON.